# Connecting ABS at <22.5 degree angle?

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent, abs

I’m trying to get my plumbing vents up into my roof joist bays. They’ll run halfway up the house until they hit a beam. I’m then going to level off the vents so they dip below the beam and connect perpendicular. They will be a soffit next to the beam to hide them.

The catch is that to angle them below the joists and maintain the proper 1/4”/ft slope, I need an angle of around 15 degrees. The smallest elbow angles I can find are 22.5.

Questions:

1) do they make elbows with smaller angles than 22.5?

2) is there a different type of connector I should look for?

3) would it be ok to use two 90 degree elbows connected horizontally? I could achieve any angle with those but do end up with a lot of 90 angles in my vents. Is that ok?

Answer (score 2):

My standard procedure for dealing with shallow angle bends when none of the prefab sizes are right, is **two of them**.

Obviously you can get the bend you want with two 90's; my point is this works with shallower angles too.  You simply have the bends in different planes, so they add up to the correct angle *in a third plane*.

Comment: And some of those 90 bends are available as “swept” ie they have a curve (not sharp 90) which are much better for the flow you are concerned about, but yes, they need more space...